# Foreman Unattended Installation

Tags: ubuntu, preseed, foreman

I am currently hard coding a preseed configuration to install foreman on a new machine together with Ubuntu 12.04. The intention is to be able to reproducably create a foreman installation which deploys openstack on brand new machines via PXE.

I think I can achieve this with my manual hacking, but to me it seems to be overkill. Is there a possibility for foreman to provision itself? Can a "temporary" foreman create an install image and provision itself?

Comment: As a developer gone ops, this is my first post on serverfault. I am disapointed, that the question was down voted, without even posting a comment - I would even appreciate a nasty one!

Answer (score 1):

Foreman itself is quite straightforward to install, download a installer script, run it. and voila 5 minutes later you have a working (yet unconfigured) foreman installation. Obviously by writing a puppet template you could provision a new foreman installation from within foreman, but the advantages of that are to little in my opinion to justify the time it takes to write the template.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to use [the puppet forge](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/) .. with the forge and 'puppet module' command, you never really have to start with a blank slate, unless you really must.

For something so intimately integrated into puppet like The Foreman, you would probably not need to modify the module to be able to use it .. You would then only have a need to identify the important parameters and set them in your manifests or hiera files.

Here is a list of [The Foreman oriented modules at the forge](http://forge.puppetlabs.com/modules?utf-8=%E2%9C%93&sort=rank&q=foreman&LeadSource=Web%20-%20Organic&Lead_Source_Description__c=google%20-%20%28not%20provided%29&utm_source__c=google&utm_medium__c=organic&utm_term__c=%28not%20provided%29&utm_content__c=null&utm_campaign__c=%28organic%29&utm_adgroup__c=null&gclid=)